# Clicking object method triggers to change the active file in explorer window

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code when you click on a method of an object, to view the code of that method, the explorer window will change the active file (where you did the click on the method) to the file of the method you clicked.

Is there a way to disable this behavior: so to open the file of the method but keep the explorer window on the file that you were working in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31025

Edit settings as followed:

```
"explorer.autoReveal": false
```